# Error running Pyomo in a virtual environment

Tags: python, pyomo, virtual-environment

I want to solve an optimization problem with pyomo in a virtual conda-environment. I installed pyomo and the glpk-Solver with "conda install-n envname packagename". When I test the solver I get the following error:

```
(venvconda) C:\Users\XXX\Synergy-Site>pyomo test-solvers glpk
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\venvconda\Scripts\pyomo-script.py", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "\\xxxx\Anwendungsdaten\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyomo\scripting\pyomo_main.py", line 82, in main
    retval = _options.func(_options)
  File "\\xxxx\Anwendungsdaten\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyomo\opt\plugins\driver.py", line 31, in test_exec
    pyomo.solvers.tests.testcases.run_test_scenarios(options)
  File "\\xxxx\Anwendungsdaten\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\tests\testcases.py", line 353, in run_test_scenarios
    rc = model_class.validate_current_solution(suffixes=model_class.test_suffixes)
  File "\\xxxx\Anwendungsdaten\Python\Python37\site-packages\pyomo\solvers\tests\models\base.py", line 205, in validate_current_solution
    with open(self.results_file,'r') as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\xxxx\\Anwendungsdaten\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages\\pyomo\\solvers\\tests\\models\\LP_block.json'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `test-solvers` script is pretty old so I would recommend trying to solve a small model as a way to test your installation instead of using the `test-solvers` script. You can check if GLPK is installed correctly by running the command `glpsol` in your Anaconda prompt. You should see output like the following:

```
$ glpsol
GLPSOL: GLPK LP/MIP Solver, v4.62
No input problem file specified; try glpsol --help
```

A small Pyomo model to test your installation can be found [here](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/blob/master/examples/doc/pyomobook/scripts-ch/minimal.py)